# How to select SQL results based on multiple tables

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, join

I need to select results from one table based on certain matching values in a couple of other tables. I have the following tables:

```
person: id, firstname, lastname
team: id, teamname
player: id, person_id(FK), team_id(FK)
coach: id, person_id(FK), team_id(FK)
```

I need to return all the coaches and players names for each team. I've only ever used inner joins, and it doesn't seem like I can use those here, so any idea how to do this?

Comment: thanks for the edit. I forgot to put the fields in a code tag on here.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the database setup like that. Why not just have one table for players and one for coaches with the team_id as the FK on both. That way you could just run something like ("select ? from coach c, player p where team_id = ?). Also I think it's good practice to use the same name for the foreign key as the corresponding field (i.e. the id field in the team table should be called "team_id" just as the FK).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This will give you the coach:

```
SELECT team.Teamname, person.Firstname, person.Lastname
FROM person
JOIN coach ON person.id = coach.person_id
JOIN team  ON coach.team_id = team.id
```

And this will give you the players:

```
SELECT team.Teamname, person.Firstname, person.Lastname
FROM person
JOIN player ON person.id = player.person_id
JOIN team  ON player.team_id = team.id
```

So, the non-elegant, simple answer is to just toss it all together with `UNION`.

Comment: +1 for the simple answer but it can be done without a UNION also if you do use UNION you should do a UNION ALL or include p.id in the select in case a Coach and a player have the same name

Comment: @cfrederich Conrad Frix has a good point here; my solution used `UNION` purposely so that it doesn't duplicate a coach that is also a player. But my solution fails to some degree if the coach and one of the players are different people with the same name! `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` is certainly a good fix; I'm going to leave my answer how it is with this caveat.

Answer (score 3):

Just use an OR in the join to Team

```
SELECT
     P.firstname,
     P.lastname,
     T.teamname
FROM
    person p id
    LEFT JOIN player pl
    ON p.id = pl.person_id
    LEFT JOIN coach c
    ON p.id = c.person_id
    LEFT JOIN team t
    ON pl.team_id = t.id
         or.c.team_id = t.id
```

Or if you perfer if and your database has COALESCE

```
   LEFT JOIN team t
        ON COALESCE(pl.team_id,c.team_id)  = t.id
```