# Combining sql statements into single statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have 4 tables say A, B, C, D.

> "D" has two columns "id", and "Cid"
>
> "C" has two columns "id", and "Bid"
>
> "B" has two columns "id", and "Aid"

If I want to get "Cid" I do `"SELECT Cid FROM D where id = value which I enter"`.

If I want to get "Bid" I do `"SELECT Bid from C where id = result of Cid from above query"`.

If I want to get "Aid" I do `"SELECT Aid from B where id =result is Bid from above query"`.

As you see, the tables are related to each other.

How can I get "Aid" directly by combining the above SQL statements; how can I get "Aid" in a single SQL statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select SQL results based on multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587514/how-to-select-sql-results-based-on-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
    select tb.Aid
      from D td
inner join C tc ON ( tc.id = td.Cid )
inner join B tb ON ( tb.id = tc.Bid )
     where d.id = :value
         ;
```

Comment: I never understand why people alias tables in queries when it's completely unnecessary. It just adds noise, no?  Sometimes it can be very useful, but in this case your query would be much easier to read (IMO) w/o.

Comment: @Madbreaks: it's a habit. experience (at least mine) shows that in maintaining queries you'll end up needing aliases anyway. contrary to your impression imho using aliases makes the queries more readable, too, especially if different tables have columns with the same name and even if technically no disambiguation is necessary. ymmv, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can certainly understand that point of view.

Answer (score 0):

First make it **one** table.

Then read on the ways [hierarchal data can be retrieved from mysql](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Answer (score -1):

Your relational structure becomes useful when you start using JOINs:

```
SELECT A.id
FROM D
JOIN C ON D.Cid = C.id
JOIN B on C.Bid = B.id
JOIN A on B.Aid = A.id
WHERE D.id = 'foo';
```