# Adding another tables column to the results of a query linked by foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a two tables connected via a foreign key:

[image: diagram]

The `reportingusers` table only has one record for each ip, and the `reports` table has many

I am looking up in the `reports` table by ID:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip FROM `reports` WHERE `id` = '346346'
```

This gets me the correct data from the reports table, however I want to expand this query to have a column with the `rep` included from the `reportingusers` table.

So the final result would look like this:

```
ip      | rep 
--------------
0.0.0.0 | 2   
1.1.1.1 | -1  
3.2.1.0 | 145
```

The rep coming from the `reportingusers` table associated with the ip. Sure I could manually do this via PHP by looking up every IP in the table to find the rep, but that means a lot of extra queries and I believe this can probably be simply done via SQL.

Looking at [questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587514/how-to-select-sql-results-based-on-multiple-tables) this is similar to what I want to do, however the question is slightly different than my goal here.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but could be better ways still

```
SELECT DISTINCT reports.ip,reportingusers.rep FROM reports 
INNER JOIN reportingusers
ON reports.ip=reportingusers.ip
WHERE `id` = '346346'
```