# Opposite of join in SQL with selecting 2 columns?

Tags: php, sql, join

I have two tables A and B which I would like to select data where both table are common in a column (`user_id`) and are not similar in another column `(A.columnX != B.columnY)`.

Actually, I would like the opposite of SQL joins.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select SQL results based on multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587514/how-to-select-sql-results-based-on-multiple-tables)

Comment: simply use something  like this SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN BON A.id = B.user_id AND A.columnX <> B.columnY

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to filter a join based on further logic, just use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    table_a.something,
    table_a.something_else,
    table_b.another_thing
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN table_b
    ON table_b.user_id = table_a.user_id
WHERE
    table_a.column_x != table_b.column_y;
```

Comment: You can also move the `WHERE` condition into the `ON` clause (using `AND`) if it would be more easily expressed that way. The two forms are syntactically identical, and treated the same by the query optimiser - it doesn't matter which form you use.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the join query as:

```
select <<Column list>> from table1 a, table2 b where a.userid=b.userid and a.columnX!=b.columnY;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I have different userids in both tables and i should say where a.userid or b.userid = M, could i add this at the end of SQL?

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As you describe the question, you seem to want `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.something, a.something_else,
       b.another_thing
FROM table_a a INNER JOIN
     table_b b
     ON b.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table_b b2
                  WHERE b2.user_id = b.user_id and
                        b2.column_y = a.column_x
                 );
```

It is unclear if you want the `user_id` comparison in the correlation clause.